# FFMPEG with SoX: configure: error: cannot find ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, sox

So I am trying to install in my Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 SoX with FFMPEG support for m4a files.

I have followed [this](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) instructions to install FFMPEG, installing only certain encoders. Finally, this is my set up:

```
ffmpeg version git-2014-01-17-3ca7085 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 17 2014 12:36:01 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --prefix=~/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I~/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L~/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=~/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      52. 62.100 / 52. 62.100
  libavcodec     55. 48.101 / 55. 48.101
  libavformat    55. 23.103 / 55. 23.103
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
```

Then, I wget SoX 14.4.1 version and try to configure with FFMPEG support like this:

```
./configure --with-ffmpeg
```

But I get this error:

```
checking for FFMPEG... no
checking libavformat/avformat.h usability... no
checking libavformat/avformat.h presence... no
checking for libavformat/avformat.h... no
checking ffmpeg/avformat.h usability... no
checking ffmpeg/avformat.h presence... no
checking for ffmpeg/avformat.h... no
configure: error: in `~/sox-14.4.1':
configure: error: cannot find ffmpeg
See `config.log' for more details
```

So I try to set PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=~/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig
./configure --with-ffmpeg
```

Getting:

```
checking for FFMPEG... yes
checking libavformat/avformat.h usability... yes
checking libavformat/avformat.h presence... yes
checking for libavformat/avformat.h... yes
checking for av_open_input_file in -lavformat... no
configure: error: in `~/sox-14.4.1':
configure: error: cannot find ffmpeg
See `config.log' for more details
```

Checking 'config.log' I see the following error:

```
| #define HAVE_LIBAVFORMAT_AVFORMAT_H 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
|
| /* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
|    Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
|    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
| #ifdef __cplusplus
| extern "C"
| #endif
| char av_open_input_file ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| return av_open_input_file ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:15862: result: no
configure:15935: error: in `~/sox-14.4.1':
configure:15937: error: cannot find ffmpeg
```

What am I missing here?
Thx!

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem, have you managed to fix it?